# Logrotate script only triggers correctly during manual execution

Tags: linux, tomcat, cron, logrotate

Good day!

I tried to use the logrotate facility of linux to rotate my tomcat logs. I created a script named tomcat under /etc/logrotate.d

```
/path/to/tomcat/catalina.out {
    missingok
    copytruncate
    daily
    rotate 10
    compress
    size 1M
}
```

Logrotate seems to be triggered daily via cron.daily but my tomcat logs are not rotated. I tried to execute the script manually by entering this command:

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Surprisingly, it worked. Do you have any idea why cron job cannot rotate it? Below is the setup in crontab:

```
0 7 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to add the following to /etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
Try running logrotate to verify:
cd /etc/cron.daily/ && ./logrotate